# How to prove the fully-faithfulness of nerve functor？

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

I know it might be a bit elementary but I‘ve just read about the defintion of nerve functor $N: Cat \rightarrow sSet$ in nLab :

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve

And Proposition 3.12 states that nerve functor is **fully and faithful**. But I can’ t get it on my own. Where can I find proof for it?

Comment: Have you tried looking into any of the references listed on the nlab page — particularly the ones under “review and exposition”? Generally, this question would be better suited to math.stackexchange than here — I’ve voted for migration and will answer it there if it gets migrated. It could also be improved by saying more about what sources you’ve looked at, and what you’ve tried for proving it yourself. Eg have you been able to prove either fullness or faithfulness individually, even if not both?

Comment: To elaborate on Peter's very on-point comment, one of the nlab references under "review and exposition" is to the [Kerodon](https://kerodon.net/tag/002L) section on the nerve functor. It might not be immediately obvious when you look at the table of contents there, but under [recovering a category from its nerve](https://kerodon.net/tag/002Y) you'll find a detailed proof of the fully faithfulness of the nerve functor. However, I'm quite keen to see what Peter or others might have to say about motivating this proof. Since I agree that such an answer would fit better on Math.SE, migration it is.